# Log entry. System: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e

Tags: log

Since updating from a new install of 18.10 to 19.04 I am getting this error in my syslog:

> Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e

What does it mean? Other than the log entry I am not experiencing any problems.

Entries above and below:

> May  6 08:18:49 steve kernel: [    1.900555] Loaded UEFI:db cert
>   'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011:
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' linked to secondary sys
>   keyring
>
> May  6 08:18:49 steve kernel: [    1.900570] Loaded UEFI:db cert
>   'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011:
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' linked to secondary sys
>   keyring
>
> May  6 08:18:49 steve kernel: [    1.900941] Couldn't get size:
>   0x800000000000000e
>
> May  6 08:18:49 steve kernel: [    1.900943] MODSIGN: Couldn't get
>   UEFI MokListRT
>
> May  6 08:18:49 steve kernel: [    1.901675] zswap: loaded using pool
>   lzo/zbud

Comment: Could you please share more logs, few lines from above & below. It will help to narrow down may be!

Comment: Since this comment I have upgraded to 19.10 and the syslog error no longer appears.

Comment: Cool, good for you!